# Wordpress search doesn't show custom post types and fields

Tags: wordpress, search, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type, meta-boxes

I have done some research on this topic and followed many tutorials but nothing seems to work, I was wondering if someone could help me out? I want to allow the search form in my Wordpress site to also include custom post types and custom meta fields. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out. THANKS!

Answer (score 2):

Archives.php only shows content of type 'post', but you can alter it to include custom post types. Add this filter to your functions.php file:

```
function namespace_add_custom_types( $query ) {
   if ( $query->is_search )
      $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'YOUR_CUSTOM_POST_HERE') );
   return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'namespace_add_custom_types' );
```

Comment: is it searching in custom post type ? check for title of the post in custom post type, next you can go for including custom meta box

Comment: Yes, the titles are searchable of the custom post type but what about the meta boxes? i have a metabox that is sex and i would like if someone searches male all the male meta fields pop up how would i go about doing that?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-fields-search/screenshots/ try this plugin, this will allow you to select custom fields to be added in search query

Comment: There is no way to do this without a plugin?

Comment: is there a way to do this without using a plugin?

Comment: Yes that would be for the custom post type title again, but what about meta fields or words within the custompost type?

Comment: why are you not using plugin, it has not issue to use plugin

Comment: I am developing a theme I do not want any plugins to be used.

Comment: then if you explore the code of this plugin, and place the relavent piece of code in you function.php

Comment: Thank you Abuzer for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress search functionality looking search query only in 'posts' table in DB, but custom fields are saved on 'post_meta' table. So, firstly you need to LEFT JOIN these two tables, secondly change query to DB, and finally - prevent duplicates in searching. Please look at this link, here is the code you must paste into functions.php with an explanation -> https://adambalee.com/search-wordpress-by-custom-fields-without-a-plugin/